# Is it possible to mock a fake element that my JS needs to perform?

Tags: javascript, jasmine

I have an object that has a `rel` attribute. That rel value carries a URL that is required for a function to run.

```
var quiz_url = $("#click-to-play-quiz").attr('rel');
var presenter = new app.views.QuizPresenter({quiz_url: quiz_url});
presenter.show();
```

Where `quiz_url` is what I want to mock in my jasmine.js spec.

Can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to create a fixture with your html, include it in jasmine spec

```
<a id="click-tooplay-quiz" rel="http://test.url" href="#"/>
```

then use jasmine jquery to check that attribute it passed

```
expect($("#click-to-play-quiz").attr('rel')).toBe("http://test.url");
```

if you need to mock variable itself probably you will have to restructure your code a bit and pass the url as a parameter to a function, for example.